# jQuery - possible plugin or method for animating background image when scrolling like Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, jquery-animate

I noticed in the Windows 8 start screen, that when scrolling the background image kind of drags the opposite way. I was wondering if there is a jQuery animation plugin or method (or CSS if possible) that can accomplish this in a web page. I have tried looking, but alas found no such thing... But jQuery always seems to have the answer for everything.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the [jQuery parallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/) plugin, or if so inclined, write your own - I have a blog post on how to add [vertical parallax scrolling](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/04/vertical-parallax.html) to a page.

Comment: Hmm. Nice! I will go with this. Thanks! :-)